# Convert code to read byte and store data

Tags: c#, csv, filereader

I am working on enhancement on someone's code.
basically, the guy wrote it to read a csv file directly from a folder path on a separated console project with the codes below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: ImportUser.exe <input.csv>");
            return;
        }

        string inputFileDirectory = args[0];
        string outputFileDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "error.csv");

        var i = 1;
        var j = 0;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFileDirectory))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileDirectory, false))
            {
                var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<RecordMapper>();
                csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
                var outCsv = new CsvWriter(writer);

                var records = csv.GetRecords<Record>();

                List<Record> BadRecords = new List<Record>();

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing record " + i);
                    record.Index = i++;
                    try
                    {
                        using (var db = new dcIngressDataContext())
                        {
                            ProcessRecord(db, record);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        j++;
                        {
                            record.Error = ex.ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine(record);
                            outCsv.WriteRecord<Record>(record);
                            outCsv.NextRecord();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i - 1 + " records processed.");
        if (j > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(j + " records not added. See error.csv for details.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I have to convert it into an api method which by I will parse in the file data in  Byte[]. How do I replace/convert the first part so that it read the byte[] and put data to List? Here is my code from controller -> Repository -> webapi.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UserImport(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        Session currentSession = Helpers.GetCurrentSession(User.Identity);
        var companyid = currentSession.CompanyId;

        try
        {
            byte[] data;
            if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (Stream inputStream = uploadFile.InputStream)
                {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                    if (memoryStream == null)
                    {
                        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }
                    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    var NewFile = new ImportUsers
                    {
                        CompanyId = companyid,
                        Content = data,
                    };

                    var upld = repository.Attachments.importUsers(NewFile);
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
            return View();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

ApiRepository

```
public WebApiResponse<ImportUsers> importUsers(ImportUsers file)
    {
        var response = Client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/attachments/importusers", file).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<WebApiResponse<ImportUsers>>().Result;
            if (apiResponse.Status == ReturnStatus.SessionInvalid)
            {
                throw new InvalidSessionException();
            }
            if (apiResponse.Status == ReturnStatus.NoAccess)
            {
                throw new NoAccessException();
            }
            return apiResponse;
        }
        else
        {
            return new WebApiResponse<ImportUsers>()
            {
                Status = ReturnStatus.Failed,
                Error = "Error connecting to server. " + response.ReasonPhrase,
                Result = null
            };
        }
    }
```

From here I will pass the byte to the webApi. I create a method and replicate the code in and it can't work.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/attachments/importusers")]
    public WebApiResponse ImportUser([FromBody]ImportUserDTO value)
    {
        var response = new WebApiResponse();

        var i = 1;
        var j = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFileDirectory))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileDirectory, false))
            {
                var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<RecordMapper>();
                csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
                var outCsv = new CsvWriter(writer);

                var records = csv.GetRecords<Record>();

                List<Record> BadRecords = new List<Record>();

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing record " + i);
                    record.Index = i++;
                    try
                    {
                        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                        {
                            ProcessRecord(db, record);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        j++;
                        {
                            record.Error = ex.ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine(record);
                            outCsv.WriteRecord<Record>(record);
                            outCsv.NextRecord();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i - 1 + " records processed.");
        if (j > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(j + " records not added. See error.csv for details.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        return response;

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working?

Comment: You need to describe the format of the input file.  If you have byte[] then the file is binary and the binary structure will determine the method of parsing. I did a binary parser last week at this posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321476/how-to-get-raw-ecg-data-from-dicom-file/51322183#51322183

Comment: @jdweng I put in the methods i created please help me see. I know I need to change the streamreader path so that it can read/convert byte[] to process but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You need to use BinaryReader which requires a Stream instead of the StreamReader :            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(inputFileDirectory);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

Comment: @jdweng Im passing in 3 datatype 'public byte[] Content { get; set; }
            public int CompanyId { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }' in the ImportUserDTO i can't think of a way to do it

Comment: How long is each field and how to you determine the length.  If you have a byte[] then you need the size.  How is the string size determined?  Is there a terminating character?  The int is simple since it is 4 bytes, unless it is a string that needs to be parsed to a number.

Comment: The webapi code (after where you say *"it can't work"*) is still reading from inputFileDirectory; it should be reading the data from the DTO, probably by putting the byte[] into a MemoryStream. And you'll need to get rid of the Console WriteLine and ReadLine calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to it by simply using MemoryStream

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(value.Content);
```

replace

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFileDirectory))
```

with

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
```